# Redirecting to `stdin`: who outputs the contents afterwards?

Tags: bash, shell, pipe, io-redirection

Consider the following example in Bash shell

```
$ echo 'test' | wc -c
5
```

Everything works as expected. Now let's change it to

```
$ echo 'test' >&0 | wc -c
test
0
```

Now, that `0` in the output makes prefect sense: `echo` has sent everything to `stdin` (which is traditionally writable) and nothing to `stdout`, so nothing gets piped over to `wc`. But how did the output appear in the console? Who printed that `test` line and when?

And finally, the third test (for platforms that support `stdbuf`)

```
$ stdbuf -i0 -o0 -e0 echo 'test' >&0 | wc -c
0
test
```

What happened here? Why did the order change?

Answer (score 3):

The `stdin` of `echo` is connected to the terminal, so that's where the output goes when you do `echo 'test' >&0`. Usually, `echo` doesn't use its stdin, but it is there, the same way it is for e.g. `cat`. On the other hand, if you run `echo foo | echo test >&0`, you get an error for "Bad file descriptor", since the pipe connected to the stdin of the second `echo` is read-only for it.

In your other snippet, with `stdbuf`, I think what happens is that it's a race between `wc` noticing the pipe in its `stdin` is closed (you redirected the write side away, so there's no-one writing to the pipe), and `echo` writing to the terminal. It's not about the buffering (which really shouldn't matter since `echo` has to flush the buffer when finishing anyway), you can get the same with `strace echo ...` or `env echo ...`. Anything on the left side that makes launching `echo` slower should have an effect. Also, remember that with just `echo | wc`, you're likely to run the shell's built-in implementation of `echo`, and with `stdbuf`, `env` or `strace`, an external `echo` runs. Builtins are faster.

In general, if you have two processes writing somewhere simultaneously, you can't make any assumptions about the order of the writes, unless they explicitly syncronize.

Comment: So, if I understood you correctly, in the first paragraph you are saying that everything written into `stdin` will also be displayed in the console (as opposed to being silently discarded). If so, is that formally specified somewhere?

Comment: @AnT, why would it be discarded? If `stdin` is connected to a terminal (probably the same one `stdout` and `stderr` are connected to, but it doesn't matter), and it's opened read-write (as you said yourself that it is), then why would any writes go anywhere else? It's the same terminal, right? I'm not even sure _how_ they could get discarded -- how is the terminal driver supposed to know if the write comes from a process holding that fd at fd number 0 instead of fd number 1? The fd numbers can even be changed with `dup2()`, and anyway, that would break the abstraction.

Comment: @AnT, as for formal specification, I suppose you'll have to look at the documentation of the behaviour of the terminal device nodes on your OS.

Comment: @AnT, ah, that first comment could be seen a bit flippant, sorry. But I'm serious in that I can't see any way it would make a difference if the terminal is open on fd 0, fd 1, or some fd >= 3. POSIX says that fds 0, 1 and 2 should be open when a process is executed, or the environment is non-conformant and may cause trouble (meaning that it technically accepts that such a thing can happen, it doesn't say that they _shall_ be open), and of course they're used by default for input and output, but other than that, I don't know anything that would make them special.

Comment: @AnT, implementation-wise, I fully expect a kernel to handle them just like any other fd, and to let userspace deal with the customs and their consequences. That would be the simple and straightforward implementation anyway. There's really no _reason_ for the kernel to stop writes to stdin, and hey, it could be useful sometimes. stderr could also be read from, to get to the user without the usual redirections getting in the way (though opening `/dev/tty` might be better), and `stty` configures the terminal on stdin (that's an `ioctl()`, not `write()`, though).

Comment: @AnT, but formal specification that it does work? I have honestly no idea. I'd expect a specification of the opposite, actually, because of the above reasons, and I've never seen one. (But that doesn't prove anything.) IIRC e.g. POSIX doesn't define much about device nodes, and what it says about exec'ing processes is just that fd 0 should be open for reading, and fds 1 and 2 for writing. So they don't _have_ to be read-write, and if they aren't then the tricks of course fail. (Try `exec 0< "$(tty)"; echo 'test' >&0 | wc -c` and you get an error.)